# Publish Windows Forms Application C# with added toolkit

Tags: c#, release, publish, krypton-toolkit

I'm publishing my first program, which I wrote in Visual Studio 2022 on one computer, and I want to run on my other computer. The program I have created is simple, but I have used the Krypton toolkit.

I have tried sending the files in the program release folder (which includes the Krypton toolkit files) to my other computer, but when trying to start the program, it says there are still missing information. I tried sharing a test program with the default toolkit the same way, and that worked just fine. How can I publish the program with the Krypton toolkit?

Comment: What error message are you getting exactly?

Comment: When trying to open the setup file on the computer which I want to run the program on, it says "Unable to retrieve the application. The application is missing necessary files. Please contact the publisher of the application." (Translated from Swedish)

Comment: Already when you try to run the setup? Then there seems to be a problem with that. How did you create the setup file?

Comment: I went into the project properties, allowed ClickOnce and then clicked published. I made sure it included the Krypton files, but I have probably done something wrong

Comment: Oh, that's not a setup file then, that's a click-once application. I'm not familiar with those, and all I know of is that this feature of the .NET Framework (which I assume you're using) is just completely broken. I'd avoid using it and use a distinct software installer application instead.

Comment: Thank you, I found a solution. When publishing it, it creates the correct files, however, these files seem to need to be placed in the exact way Visual Studio creates them. When transfering them to my other computer, I simply transferred the files (Not the maps in which they were placed). By creating and placing the files in maps exactly like Visual Studio did on the first computer, everything worked. I will look into using a software installer application next time.